# addClass after timeout when user scrolls to bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery/javascript code here on which i would like to set a timer.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  var sheight = $(window).height();
  var dheight = $(document).height();

  if (scroll+sheight == dheight) {
    $(".footer").addClass('footer-show-all');
  } else {
    $(".footer").removeClass('footer-show-all');
  }
}, 500);
```

The code itself works! it shows only 20px of my footer when scrolling in general and shows All when you reach the bottom. But the bottom seems to come up too fast. So why does this timer not work?

---

---

Also I have my page in three different sections, (header, main and footer). Every thing works well in my page except for one part... My content slides over my menu. but i want my menu to be in front at all times.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ssLkp86L/2/)

Thanks in advance for your help and please don't bash me too much.. Still learning here!

Comment: Thanks blex for edit.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's nothing personal, but people are looking for answers on this site and want to find them easily. Details about you can be added to your profile, though :) PS: Your jsFiddle is causing an error (open your JS console by hitting `F12`) because you did not define the $.cookie plugin. I added it here: https://jsfiddle.net/1svp87dk/

Comment: No I understand! Thanks again. And yeah i forgot to take that out. Thanks for the tip (jsFiddle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So why does this timer not work?

Because this is not a timer, and is not valid code, even if no error appears.
 [jQuery's .scroll()](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) does not have a `delay` parameter.

That delay can either be added to your CSS:

```
.footer-show-all {
    /* keep your existing styles here */
    -webkit-transition-delay: .5s;
    transition-delay: .5s;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/h91jnbrk/)

---

Or to your JS, using a `setTimeout`:

```
var timer;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer); // Will avoid launching tons of timers every time you scroll
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
            sheight = $(window).height(),
            dheight = $(document).height();
        $(".footer").toggleClass('footer-show-all', (scroll+sheight == dheight));
    }, 500);
});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/fa5cy2eb/)

---

> My content slides over my menu.

That's because your `#header` has a `z-index` of -10, and your content, 10. If you want your menu to stay on top, either the whole header has to be on top, or the menu has to be outside of the header, and have a `z-index` of more than 10.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed this about my header and the menu. Thanks for the explenation about the jQuery though. I didn't know this does not work on .scroll! Feels good to learn!

Comment: @Marciano' No problem, I'm always glad to help! I made a little change to the JS part, please have a look at it.

Comment: I had a look, and would like to salute you. I had been thinking about using a toggle for it before, but I hadn't yet learned how to incorporate the scroll+sheight==dheight part. Now thanks to you I learned how to! Can't stop thanking you I suppose haha!